# How can I delete old IP configurations received via DHCP on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dhcp

I noticed in the log of a DKIM verifier plugin for Thunderbird (that retrieves DNS servers to query from the OS configuration) that my Windows registry still has IP addresses for name server that belong to my previous ISP.

Searching the Windows registry for the IP address gets me a complete DHCP configuration once served by the router of my student house. Can I remove the keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{ID}` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Adapters\{ID}` (where the latter refers to the former and {ID} is the same UUID), or is there a safer way?

(Me and my desktop machine moved twice since I used the DHCP configuration with these DNS servers. The network connections panel in the Network and Sharing center currently shows one LAN connection: *Local Area Connection 3* connected to *Network 5*.)

Comment: First of all always check CurrentControlSet. ControlSet001, ControlSet002 etc may be older ControlSets that may not be relevant. Also see if ipconfig /flushdns helps.

Comment: Following https://support.microsoft.com/kb/100010, I found that the same keys exist in ControlSet002 and that the CurrentControlSet is ControlSet001. CS 2 is the 'last known good'. `ipconfig /flushdns` did not change anything relating to this situation.